# Bind the asp control while typing the text in Text box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a text box and a repeater control. I need to bind the data to repeater control when a user is entering the text in text box. This should happen without clicking on the enter key or mouse click.

Repeater should be binded with the names starts with the given string in the text box

anybody have an idea?

Comment: I didn't get the solution till now...Can anybody help me out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.. This http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/ajax/ajax-search-csharp.aspx helps me to get what exactly I want with minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that what you want is to enter the same value from the textbox on to a repeater column. 
You can use the onchange event of the textbox to call javascript and update your repeater.

Comment: not the same value...Example: if I enter 'L' then the cities starts with letter 'L' should bind to the control.

Answer (score 0):

ASPX

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" /> <div id="Container"> <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" 
    OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">   <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt"></asp:Repeater>   </ContentTemplate> </asp:UpdatePanel>

<input type="text" id="Container" onkeyup='update(document.getElementById("Container").value)'>
```

JS

```
function update(args)
{
__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', args);
}
```

C#

```
  protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //bind reapeter
    }
```